# There was an error downloading metadata from the address

Tags: wcf, service-reference

I am trying to add service reference.

There was an error downloading metadata from the address

this is the error which is being displayed again and again?

Please help

Comment: please publish the wsdl or send me in email

Comment: if it is one small file paste it here. if it is big and have referenced files (e.g. "import" tags) send them all to me. I want to reproduce it

Comment: basically after clicking on add service reference when i press ok it shows me a error : There was an error downloading metadata from the address please enter a valid URL

Comment: Please post your web.config of the service you are trying to add.

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: does we require to add something in web config of Visual studio 2010 to make this error out..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are atleast 4 possibilities:

- The metadata exchange mex endpoint is not defined
- metadata exchange is not enabled
- You are using the wrong address
- You are being blocked by some security setting

Try the url in a browser to see that it returns a wsdl

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: The type 'SilverlightApplication6.Web.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Comment: Browser displays the above message while posting the URL.

Answer (score 19):

You may also just need to build / rebuild the project.

Answer (score 4):

It was happening the same to me and I found that I've had forgotten to add the "Service Contract" and the "Operation Contract" annotations on the interface of my WCF service

Comment: Same if you forgot `[DataContract]` on classes that you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Just try to Build the project without any error and give service reference again.

Comment: This ans Helped for me

Answer (score 1):

In Web.config file I changed :

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
    contract="IAsyncTaskService"/>
```

to this :

```
<endpoint address="" binding="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
    contract="DuplexService.Web.IAsyncTaskService"/>
```

and error was removed.
Zeni

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the project first, if that does not fix it, try changing the property **httpGetEnabled** from FALSE to TRUE in your web.config.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check IIS is serving the service URL. In my case, I had changed my Windows password, but had forgotten that these credentials were being used by IIS in both the application and the app pool.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an oldie, but I thought I would add what worked for me so that I can find it again down the road ;)

In my case, the AppPool user didn't have access the %Windir%\temp, which apparently is necessary in order for the MEX data to be generated.

Shout out to Amy Peng in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bcf678a2-7ada-441c-9860-cf452d925009/adding-webservice-client-to-a-net-45-service-fails-when-adding-from-remote-server?forum=wcf) for her tip!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility in this situation is that there is no endpoint listening. I.e., the service you are trying to add isn't "up". I made this mistake when trying to add a reference to a WCF service I was working on, but I forgot to Open it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this one : Adding a service reference failed with a message "Method not allowed".

The wsdl worked fine in my browser..

The reason was that I configured the endpoint to listen on `http://0.0.0.0:6000/mex`, which the "Add Service Reference" tool doesn't seem to like. Changing it to a real IP address made it work (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:6000/mex`)