# There was an error downloading the metadata from the address

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-mvc-5, client

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET and Entity Framework, at some point, i have come to use a SOAP web service in order to include the electronic signature to my application.

I'm creating a PDF file which needs to be signed by another company, they gave us the Endpoints available in order to communicate with them.

The thing is, i'm very new to this kind of web services, in fact i never used one before.

So, in my application i go to the solution explorer, references, i try to add a new service reference, i type the end point URL there but it returns this error :

> There was an error downloading the metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address.

In general, i would really appreciate some guidance in order for me to complete this task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See following.  Do not use obsolete code but replace with newer code on the posting : http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/

Answer (score 0):

Please post the service endpoint if possible.

If it ends in ".svc" you need to append "?wsdl" before you try and generate a service reference to it in Visual Studio.

If you've already done that, can you access the wsdl in a browser?

Some other ideas:
[There was an error downloading metadata from the address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618181/there-was-an-error-downloading-metadata-from-the-address)