# Unable to consume WCF services from my .net MVC application

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

Trying to consume WCF web service inside newly created .net (MVC) application.

I have done below step.
1. created a new mvc application.
2. Going to add service reference.
3. paste the URL "http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_AirBook/AirService.svc"
4. Getting error.
There was an error downloading 'http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_AirBook/AirService.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_AirBook/AirService.svc

Need to consume web service. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618181/there-was-an-error-downloading-metadata-from-the-address

Answer (score 0):

For the WCF service without sharing the Metadata of web service, we can only consume the service after we have known the service contract, like the below form.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();
}
```

Then we call the service by using ChannelFactory.

```
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://serviceaddress:8008");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.SayHello();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The above service you try to consume hasn't published the service metadata. Therefore, either we change the server settings to enable service metadata or we have to know the service contract, so as to make a successful call.
About how to enable the service metadata, it depends on the way to publish the service.
Here is a common configuration on the server-side, we need to configure an extra MEX endpoint.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1"></endpoint>
        <!--Add an extra endpoint to exchange the service metadata-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.